# twig вывод переменной

Tags: symfony, twig

есть массив vid
нужно вывести в цикле другого массива тип `{{vid.0}} {{vid.1}}`и т.д
вот другой

```
    {% for image in page.media.images   %}
  <div class="vid">
    <img data-lazy="{{ image.url }}"/>

  </div>

{% endfor %}
```

как записать с loop.index внутри цикла типа `{{vid.loop.index}}` но так не работает

хотелось бы так

```
{% for image in page.media.images   %}
  <div class="vid">
    <img data-lazy="{{ image.url }}"/>
{{vid.loop.index}}
  </div>

{% endfor %}
```

как правильно

Comment: `{% set vid_index = loop.index %}` https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/set.html

Comment: пробовал {{vid.vid_index}} не работает....

Comment: и не будет работать

Comment: Если я правильно понял `{% for key, user in users %}`. в документации

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я понял вопрос это должно вам подойти:

```
{% set images = ['ewqewq', 'ewqewq', 'ewqewq',] %}
{% set vid = ['raz', 'dwa', 'tri',] %}

{% for key,image in images   %}
  <div class="vid">
      {{ vid[key] }}
  </div>

{% endfor %}
```

Результат:

```
<div class="vid">
    raz
</div>

<div class="vid">
    dwa
</div>

<div class="vid">
    tri
</div>
```